# Wall art sizing - how to convert between inch and cm?

Tags: painting

I need to convert size of the paintings between inches and cm.

Is there a preferred way to convert between inch and cm in wall art sizing?  I see many online stores where for example `8x14 inch` artwork is converted to a metric `20x35cm`. Even though `14 inch` equals `35.56 cm`

Which sizing is more accurate - imperial inch, or metric cm? Or is it somewhere in between? Any other advice on converting is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are seeing online store references that sell items manufactured for US sales primarily, the inch figures are more likely going to be accurate. The conversion results, for your example, in 35.56 cm, but for marketing purposes, rounding is acceptable.

I have no experience in metric-following countries, but I would expect the reverse to be true. It is practical to expect a metric-sized frame to be 35 cm, but if it is going to list the imperial measurement, it would list it as 14 inches, rather 13.xx inches.

If measurements have to be precise for your purposes, ensure that the specifications are clearly listed, or request same from the vendor. I have purchased imperial-based items but required to know the accurate metric dimensions for a project. The vendor in both cases was able to provide more accurate numbers than the marketing copy listed.

Comment: Country of origin as the most likely indicator of imperial vs metric system makes a lot of sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

this link shows a list of [common sizes for frames](http://www.schleiper.com/eshopexpress/series/8430-peacock-ready-made-3d-lijst-esdoorn-fineer-hout?category_id=2081&lang=nl) in a Really Good Art Supply shop here in Gent, Belgium, Europe

for example 24x30, 30x30 etc .. measured in centimetres.

as for accuracy .. just choose the size that suits the image and the wishes of the client .. measure in whichever units you like ;-)